# Roslyn ignores missing assembly references when loading project?

Tags: c#, .net, reference, roslyn

I can't figure out how to get an error when Roslyn loads a project with missing assembly references. The reference would be in the csproj file like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="SomeLibrary" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If SomeLibrary exists, the semantic tree will load properly and types will be in their appropriate namespace.  If SomeLibrary does not exist, Roslyn seems to go on it's merry way and just assumes any missing types exist in the global namespace.  How do I get Roslyn to report this error?

I've include some code snippets for more context:

```
MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
workspace.LoadMetadataForReferencedProjects = true;
workspace.SkipUnrecognizedProjects = false;

Project project = workspace.OpenProjectAsync("SomeProject.csproj").Result;

// Project loads no problem, even though a referenced assembly is missing...help
```

Comment: We started to make an API for this, but didn't finalize it as you can see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/e93122130cb48ba3d20beb601fd19a9d877cc9ba/src/Workspaces/Core/Portable/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs#L265). Although there'd be some extra work to hook that up to MSBuildWorkspace. You could file a bug to at least track the request.

Comment: What about using the same API for project errors that already exists for Compilation errors? GetDiagnostics?

Comment: We separated them, because if there's project errors it probably means the Compilation errors are meaningless, and it's a lot cheaper in that case not to compute them at all.

Comment: I meant adding a GetDiagnostics method to the Project class.  If there were errors in the project file, I would want to print the details about the project errors to the user, not just fail with no error message.  This would also help with consistency if the api for errors in a Project was the same for errors in a Document.

Answer (score 2):

Roslyn doesn't throw any errors when loading projects that are missing references and this is by design. The authors want to allow users to reason about any types that the compiler can figure out even if it can't figure out all of the types. (This allows IDE features like GoToDefinition to work even if some references are missing or can't be resolved)

If you're looking to discover whether or not errors exist in your project you can create a compilation and get error diagnostics. Building on your example:

```
Project project = await workspace.OpenProjectAsync("SomeProject.csproj");
var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
var errors = compilation.GetDiagnostics().Where(n => n.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);
if(errors.Any())
{
    //Fix your references
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick helpful answer.  This is what I was looking for, and thanks for the explanation on the reasoning behind this design.

Comment: Ok it looks like I'm still not getting the missing assembly references.  If the referenced assemblies are being used, then it will report that it cannot find the type definition, however, I'm not able to see whether or not roslyn was able to find an assembly reference.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So it looks like Roslyn has no API for getting certain kinds of project errors? It can report semantic errors in files, but errors in project files, like missing assembly references, are just ignored and there's no way of getting at them?

Comment: It looks that way. Missing references don't seem to be considered as errors themselves. They just possibly cause errors elsewhere in your project when you are using types from missing referenced assemblies.